# Labels and "Control flow commands not allowed in toplevel" (Possible LTA error message)

Tags: raku

This code:

```
FOO:
"Hey".say;
for <1 2> { 
    say "1";
    last FOO
}
```

Prints

```
Hey
1
Control flow commands not allowed in toplevel
```

The last error message is eliminated if "Hey".say is taken off; this probably means that what the error is actually saying is that *non* control flow commands are not allowed right behind a label. But [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Label) (which [needs to be improved](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2624) cites loops as an "example", and [the grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L952) indicates it should be in front of a statement. So the question is: can it be used for if statements, or just loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is different if you have this code inside another scope:

```
{
    FOO:
    "Hey".say;
    for <a b> {
        .say;
        last FOO
    }
}
# Hey
# a
# labeled last without loop construct
```

which is also LTA in that it doesn't mention the name of the label.

But in short: Perl 6 doesn't currently have a `goto`.  Currently, labels are only usable as a way to specify which loop construct you want to `next`, `redo` to or `last` out of.  By putting a statement between the label and the loop construct, you're effectively using it as a `goto`, which is still Not Yet Implemented.

But indeed a ticket about the LTAness of both errors, seems in place for me.

Also, using the `FIRST` phaser as an alternative, seems to have the same issue:

```
FOO:
for <a b> { 
    FIRST "Hey".say;
    .say;
    last FOO;
}   
# Hey
# a
# labeled last without loop construct
```

But runs fine without the specific label:

```
FOO:
for <a b> { 
    FIRST "Hey".say;
    .say;
    last;
}   
# Hey
# a
```

The latter issue most definitely is worth a rakudo issue: added as https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2699 .